# Double class in .solution environment and modyfing the label of the .solution environment via css

Tags: html, css, quarto

I am building a book using `quarto` where I need to use theorems, lemmas, corollaries, ..., etc. According to the documentation in quarto, [here](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/cross-references.html#theorems-and-proofs), you can create `proof`, `remark`, and `solution` environments. I am going to use these environments because in the future I will need also to render the book in `Latex` and not only in `html`.

I have the following reproducible example in relation to a `.qmd` where the `styles.css` is empty:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
format: 
  html:
    css: styles.css
editor: visual
---

## My proof

::: proof
The proof.
:::

## My solution

::: solution
The solution.
:::
```

I inspect the code generated by `html` in a web browser and in relation to these environments I get the following:

### Proof environment

```
<div class="proof">
<p><span class="proof-title">
<em>Proof</em>. 
</span>The proof.</p>
</div>
```

### Solution environment

```
<div class="solution proof">
<p><span class="proof-title">
<em>Solution</em>. 
</span>The solution.</p>
</div>
</section>
```

Taking into account the above information and pointing out that I am a beginner using `html` and `css` I want to know the following items:

- Why quarto creates 2 classes for the solution environment? Is this problematic or a bug?
- How can I modify the label inside `<em>Solution</em>` that belongs to the classes `solution` and `proof-title` without affecting the `proof` class via the `styles.css` file?

Comment: You can target the `Solution` label using the CSS selector `.solution.proof-title`.

Comment: Ok. So you can use multiple class selectors. Thank you. It works with .solution.proof-title.em { ... }. Do you know the logic of using also the class `proof`  for the .solution environment?

Comment: Can you specify this as an answer and not as a comment so I can accept your answer in relation to using .solution.proof-title.em { ... } and the part about "ensure consistent style with the Proof environment"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, AFAIK, the reason for using the class `proof` for the "Solution" environment is to ensure consistent style (outlook) with the "Proof" environment, that is, both the Proof and the Solution environment share some CSS properties via the `.proof` class.

And you can target the "Solution" label using the CSS selector `.solution. proof-title`.